# Android remove font padding on line breaks

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How do I remove the space created after this text line breaks:

[image]

The .XML looks like this:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_user_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_16dp"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_8dp"
            android:text="@{job}"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/void_black"
            app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_work_outline_white_18dp"
            app:drawableTint="@color/void_black"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_separator1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/v_separator1"
            tools:text="Pharmacy Assitant/Pharmacy Sales Staff" />
```

Comment: Does your text view have root layout like linear or relative?

Comment: ah yes actually it was inside a constraint layout

Comment: bro, could you share your root as well? constraint layout can be problematic sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for justification

```
android:justificationMode="inter_word"
```